# Stop if statement in async function from returning undefined instantly?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, asynchronous, async-await

I've got the following async code.

```
const dlcOrNot = async (file) => {
  console.log('Unpacking dlc file...')
  if (file.indexOf('.dlc') > -1) {
    await decrypt.upload(file, (err, response) => {
      const links = response.success.links;
      writeFile('urls.txt', String(links).replace(/,/g, '\n'), 'utf-8', () => {
        return 'urls.txt';
      });
    });
  } else {
    return file;
  };
};
```

My problem is the if statement returns undefined instantly before `decrypt.upload()` ran, how can I make it wait for the function inside to return its value?

Comment: if `decrypt.upload` takes a callback, it will unlikely return a promise. You can only `await` expressions that return a promise though, you will need to promisify your call. You should then also promisify `writeFile` (separately) and use a second `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only `await` a promise.

`decrypt.upload` does not return a promise.

Replace it with a promise.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) covers converting a function which takes a callback to one which returns a promise.

Comment: That seems to be a common inquiry herein.